# What's the tip about renderer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use the vscode, a tip shows in the right bottom corner. 'The standard renderer integrated the terminal works slowly on your computer. Using the renderer based on DOM maybe improve the performance. Switch?'
I haven't seen the tip and how should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Settings` => `terminal.integrated.rendererType`

Comment: Thank you~ This' s the first time for me to check the setting.